# using function to read a matrix in file .txt

Tags: c++, c, function, file, matrix

Im trying to read a .txt file with the values of a matrix [n]x[m] by using a function and then call it in my main but I am having some problems... Here is the read function:

```
bool read_file(int row, int column, char *file_name, float **elems)
    {
    int i, j;
    FILE *pfile;

    fopen_s(&pfile, file_name, "r");
    if (pfile == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    fscanf_s(pfile, "%d", &row);
    fscanf_s(pfile, "%d", &column);
    //printf_s("%d %d\n", row,column);

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            fscanf_s(pfile, "%f", &elems[i][j]);
            //printf("%f\n", elems[i][j]);
        }
    }return true;
 }
```

My program asks me to do product between two matrices and i have to do it by 2 types of input, keybord or file. I used in my main if-else to choose between the 2 inputs. When it does keybord input, everything goes right (dinamic alocation is working as well as the product of matrices). I then call the function like this in the main:

```
int main(){
int i, j, row1, column1, row2, column2;

char* file_name1 = { "C:\\Users\\Lc\\Documents\\Matrix1.txt" };
char* file_name2 = { "C:\\Users\\Lc\\Documents\\Matrix2.txt" };
if (...) {
    ...
    /* Input by keybord. */ 
    ...
}     
else if(...){  /*Input by file*/
read_file(row1, column1, file_name1, matrix1);
read_file(row2, column2, file_name2, matrix2);
...
}
...
```

And then it says matrix1 and matrix2 are undefined... I understand why they are undefined but my problem is that i dont know how to define them like i did with the keybord input

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in your code, nor anything which can be used as one! Provide a [mcve] and remove the tag of the unrelated language, C or C++ - pick one!.

Answer (score 0):

`float **elems` is a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of floats.  You can create such a thing by calling malloc() in a loop.

Note the way it's used in your code:

```
fscanf_s(pfile, "%f", &elems[i][j]);
```

So `elems[0..N]` are meant to point to the rows.  First, allocate the outer array:

```
float** elems = malloc(row * sizeof(float*));
assert(elems);
```

That's one `float*` for each row.  Then, allocate each row:

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    elems[i] = malloc(column * sizeof(float));
    assert(elems[i]);
}
```

Now `elems` points to an array of `float*` initialized with each element pointing to an array of `float` (which numbers are uninitialized).